# For loop on vector is slow

Tags: java, for-loop, vector, web-applications, load

I have a vector which has around 50000 elements. There are functions which try to search a particular element in this vector. Sometimes it takes around 7-8sec. Can anyone help me in figuring out the reason.

It is a java web application running on apache tomcat

```
 for (int iLoop = 0; iLoop < oVec.size(); iLoop++) {
                    MyStructure oMyStruct = (MyStructure) oVec.elementAt(iLoop);
                    if (oMyStruct.sElement.equals(SearchFor.trim())) {
                        oMyResultVector.add(oMyStruct);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: By saying vector you actually mean `java.util.Vector` or any kind of `java.util.List`? `java.util.Vector` is somewhat special and usage is actually discouraged as it brings a lot of synchronization overhead with it as all methods of `java.util.Vector` are synchronized. However in most real world scenarios this is not the way you want to synchronize on a list, leaving you with the overhead...

Comment: On top of which there is no good reason to use `java.util.Vector` in non-legacy code, and hasn't been for about 19 years.

Comment: I believe as long you don't provide more information about ... 1) How is `oVec` created. 2) Of what kind is your application single-/multitrheaded? 3) How did you identify that this piece of code is the part which consumes that much time? ... it's more guessing what could be the problem.